# How to precompile gulp-handlebars helpers?

Tags: javascript, gulp, handlebars.js, precompile

I am precompiling my templates into JS using gulp-handlebars but I am having trouble getting custom handlebars helpers to also precompile. Does anyone know if there is any support/way to precompile custom helper methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that gulp-handlebars can use a specific handlebars library, essentially overriding its default. So, by just creating my own module and registering some helpers, and feeding that into the handlebars call, things are working locally.

```
// helpers.js
var handlebars  = require('handlebars');

handlebars.registerHelper('upper', function(str){
   return str.toUpperCase();
});

module.exports = handlebars;
```

And then in the gulpfile (something like this):

```
var handlebars = require('./src/js/helpers.js');

gulp.task('handlebars', function(){
  gulp.src('src/html/*.html')
      .pipe(gulp_handlebars({handlebars: handlebars})) // override library here
});
```

Comment: Yup. A few things had to be changed in prod environment such as copying over the helpers.js file, but yes it did work.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I was using a different suite of modules and didn't even have to override the library – the require operation itself was all it took. Also: you should mark your own answer as correct, that's cool by Stackoverflow's standards.

Comment: … aand stopped working; can only guess that this may stem from some node autoupdate + gulp misbehaving

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Browserify and optionally watchify and need the output to be a commonjs style module, gulp-defineModule will use a require('Handlebars') in the compiled template file.
This negates any registered helpers that you had passed into gulp-handlebars custom library option (see above). Here is an example of the output file we don't want:

```
// template.js
var Handlebars = require("handlebars");
module.exports = Handlebars.template({"compiler":[7,">= 4.0.0"]...
```

**1:** To fix this, create a helpers.js file that requires the handlebars library, adds the helpers, and then exports the library. Use gulp-defineModule's require option to pass in the handlebars library with the helpers like so:

```
.pipe(defineModule('node', {
        require: {
          Handlebars: '../helpers'
        }
      })
    )
```

this will produce:

```
// template.js
var Handlebars = require("../helpers");
module.exports = Handlebars.template({...
```

Note that the relative path will be from the outputfile, and be careful on prod where filepaths may change.

**2:** Another way is to use gulp-wrap to define the module exactly how you want it. Something like:

```
.pipe(wrap('module.exports = function(Handlebars) {return Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>) }'))
```

then in main-js:

```
var Handlebars = require('./helpers');
var template = require('./template)(Handlebars);
```