# Custom helpers with gulp-handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a custom helper for handlebars compiled in the server.
I've tried this approach: [How to precompile gulp-handlebars helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491782/how-to-precompile-gulp-handlebars-helpers)

I get this if I log the handlebars version I'm using inside gulp-handlebars:

```
helpers: { blockHelperMissing: [Function],
 each: [Function],
 helperMissing: [Function],
 if: [Function],
 unless: [Function],
 log: [Function],
 lookup: [Function],
 with: [Function],
 multiply: [Function] },
```

So I see that 'upper' which is the helper I inserted is there. But then in the client, I either get

> Uncaught Error: Missing helper: upper

or if I use the notation `\{{upper string}}` it doesn't work. Can anyone help me? Maybe I'm missing something.

Here is my helpers.js:

```
// helpers.js
var handlebars  = require('handlebars');

handlebars.registerHelper('multiply', function(a,b){
   return a*b;
});

module.exports = handlebars;
```

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var wrap = require('gulp-wrap');
var declare = require('gulp-declare');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var handlebars = require('gulp-handlebars');

var handlebarsh = require('./app/lib/helpers.js');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./public/client/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/client/css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./public/client/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('templates', function(){
  gulp.src('app/assets/client/templates/modules/*.hbs')
    .pipe(handlebars({
      handlebars: handlebarsh,
   }))
    .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
    .pipe(declare({
      namespace: 'Orochi.templates',
      noRedeclare: true, // Avoid duplicate declarations
    }))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/client/assets/templates/js/'));
});

gulp.task('watch',['templates'], function () {
    gulp.watch('app/assets/client/templates/modules/*.hbs' , ['templates']);
    gulp.watch('./public/client/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

and the template:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="animals-wrapper">
      {{#each labels}}
         <div class="animal-wrapper" animal="{{@index}}">
            <div class="animal-image" style="'background-position: ' {{multiply 2 2}}'px 0px;'"></div>
            <div class="animal-label"></div>
         </div>
      {{/each}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue